# What is the common size of SSL certificate? (give or take)

Tags: ssl-certificate

I can't find any information about the usual size of SSL certificate.

- **What is their common size ? (give or take ?)**

I am not looking for an exact value, something like `usually between 8MB and 10MB` will be considered accurate enough.

Comment: You're too high by several orders of magnitude. They're measured in _kilobytes_, and single digits of them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I intentionally used exaggerated values. :)

Comment: Upvoted!  Perfectly valid question.  FYI: SSL certs may contain styling elements, like, `\n`, which don't contribute to the cryptographic processing whatsoever.  If you think it's a perfect bitwise scheme, think again.

Answer (score 5):

2 - 4 KiB.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    1679 Jan 25  2016 cert.key
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user user    3138 Jan 28  2016 cert.pem
```

Comment: Your `cert.pem` has a whole certificate chain, too!